# How much overhead does python numpy tolist() add?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, wrapper

I am using a python program that uses numpy array as standard data type for arrays. For the heavy computation I pass the arrays to a C++ library. In order to do so, I use [pybind](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). However, I am required to use python `list`. I do the conversion from `numpy` array and `list` via:

```
NativeSolver.vector_add(array1.tolist(), array2.tolist(), ...)
```

How much overhead does this conversion generate? I hope it doesn't create a whole new copy. Numpy reference says:

> **ndarray.tolist()**
>
> Return a copy of the array data as a (nested) Python list. Data items
> are converted to the nearest compatible Python type.

Comment: I found references to the buffer protocol and numpy on the `pybind` github and documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot. For simple built-in types, you can use `sys.getsizeof` on an object to determine the memory overhead associated with that object (for containers, this does not include the values stored in it, only the pointers used to store them).

So for example, a `list` of 100 smallish `int`s (but greater than 256 to avoid small `int` cache) is  (on my 3.5.1 Windows x64 install):

```
>>> sys.getsizeof([0] * 100) + sys.getsizeof(0) * 100
3264
```

or about 3 KB of memory required. If those same values were stored in a `numpy` `array` of `int32`s, with no Python objects per number, and no per object pointers, the size would drop to roughly 100 * 4 (plus another few dozen bytes, for the `array` object overhead itself), somewhere under 500 bytes. The incremental cost for each additional small `int` is 24 bytes for the object (though it's free if it's in the small int cache for values from -5 to 256 IIRC), and 8 bytes for the storage in the `list`, 32 bytes total, vs. 4 for the C level type, roughly 8x the storage requirements (and you're still storing the original object too).

If you have enough memory to deal with it, so be it. But otherwise, you might trying looking at a wrapping that lets you pass in buffer protocol supporting objects (`numpy.array`, `array.array` on Py3, `ctypes` arrays populated via memoryview slice assignment, etc.) so conversion to Python level types isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will be new copy.  The data layout for an array is very different from that of a list.

An array has attributes like shape and strides, and a 1d data buffer that contains the elements - just a contiguous set of bytes.  It's the other attributes and code that treats them as floats, int, strings, 1d, 2d etc.

A list is a buffer of pointers, with each pointer pointing to an object else where in memory.  It may point to a number, a string, or another list.  It is not going to point to the array's databuffer or elements in it.

There are interfacing numpy arrays with compiled code and C arrays that make use of the array data buffer. `cython` is a common on.  There is also a whole documentation section on the C API for numpy.  I know anything about `pbind`. If it requires a list interface it may not be the best.

When I've done `timeit` tests with `tolist()` it hasn't appeared to be that expensive.

=======================

But looking at the `pybind11` github I find a number of references to `numpy`, and this

http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#numpy-support

documentation page.  It supports the buffer protocol, and numpy arrays.  So you shouldn't have to go through the `tolist` step.

```
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
void f(py::array_t<double> array);
```

Comment: I know about that. I do not want to give up STL data types for some pybind11 data types. I wound up using SWIG now. In my view SWIG is the only wrapper that allows python and c++ files to remain as untouched as possible.